# How to map a single subdomain to a certain user's public_html directory with Apache2?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I'm trying to map **daniel.mydomain.tld** to **/home/daniel/public_html** instead of **/var/www**, while **mydomain.tld** should still point to **/var/www**.

So far I have enabled mod **vhost_alias** using `a2enmod vhost_alias`.

Furthermore I edited **sites-enabled/000-default.conf** to

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.tld
        ServerAdmin www@localhost
        ServerAlias mydomain.tld
        DocumentRoot "/var/www"
        AccessFileName .htaccess
        <Directory "/var/www">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and created **sites-enabled/daniel.conf** with the following content

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
        ServerName daniel.mydomain.tld
        ServerAlias daniel.mydomain.tld
        ServerAdmin www@localhost
        DocumentRoot "/home/daniel/public_html"
        AccessFileName .htaccess
        <Directory "/home/daniel/public_html">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once I was done I restarted the server using `service apache2 restart`.

When I load up **mydomain.tld** in my browser I get to the index.php which is located in **/var/www**, so that works like expected.

Trying to browse **mydomain.tld/~daniel/** works just fine, too, showing me the contents of user daniel's **/home/daniel/public_html** folder.

However, visiting **daniel.mydomain.tld** brings up **403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server.**

What am I doing wrong? How do I map **daniel.mydomain.tld** to **/home/daniel/public_html** folder?

I'm on **Debian 8 (Jessie)** running **Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)**.

Comment: Check if Apache2 user has read permissions on that folder. Also you'd probably want to add "Order Allow, Deny;  Allow from all" to your Directory section. Also if you want to show the contents of that folder (not index file) you have to enable Auto Index like you have on your mydomain.tld directive: Options Indexes.

Comment: The problem was `Option FollowSymLinks`, removing that option made it behave exactly the way I need it to. I assume it clashed with the permissions.  Thanks for the tips though, I'll probably add `Indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `Option FollowSymLinks` made it behave exactly like I wanted it to.